# Animation with Ajax, and CSS3

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, animation, transition

I am creating a little script that allows me to slide my content sections in and out though Ajax and CSS. I have have successfully made it slide in on page loads from the top but I have one problem, sliding out!

I wrote a clip for 'aniOut' that works also but I cant seem to make one load before the other in transition. I have tried a few things but I either have the page lock up, stop loading, or simply not initiate correctly.  I included the the working code with the whole 'aniIn' CSS because it contains ability to function on -moz -webkit but only the basic animation code for 'aniOut' to save on the space of my thread.

*Can someone push me towards a resources to help me learn what I need to do?*

My site is live with the working slide in at [The Mind Company](http://www.themindspot.com).

CSS:

```
   header {
      z-index:100;
      position:relative;
      display: block;
      background-color: #272727;
      height:100px;}

    #contentBody {
      min-height:48em;}

    footer {
      position:relative;
      display: block;
      background-color: #272727;
      height:168px;  }

    #aboutPage { 
      display:none;}

    #productPage { 
      display:none;}

    #contactPage { 
      display:none;}

    .aniIn {
z-index:0;
-webkit-animation-name: ANIMATEin;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;

-moz-animation-name: ANIMATEin;
-moz-animation-duration: 1s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;

/* Currently Not Working in browsers: Is planed for implimentation in later versions. */
animation-name: ANIMATEin;
animation-duration: 1s;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-timing-function: ease-in;

-ms-animation-name: ANIMATEin;
-ms-animation-duration: 1s;
-ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}

@-webkit-keyframes ANIMATEin {
from {
margin-top:-3000px;
}
to {
margin-top:0px;
}
}

@-moz-keyframes ANIMATEin {
from {
margin-top:-3000px;
}
to {
margin-top:0px;
}
}

@keyframes ANIMATEin {
from {
margin-top:-3000px;
}
to {
margin-top:0px;
}
}

.aniOut {
z-index:0;
animation-name: ANIMATEout;
animation-duration: 1s;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}

@keyframes ANIMATEout {
from {
margin-top:0px;
}
to {
margin-top:3000px;
}
}
```

Java Script:

```
function $_(IDS) { return document.getElementById(IDS); }

function ani(){
    document.getElementById(classID).className ='aniOut';
}

function checkPage(classID, url){   
    var tmp = '';
    var sel = document.getElementsByTagName('section');
    for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++){
        if (sel[i].id == classID) { tmp = 'block' } else { tmp = 'none' }
        $_(classID).className ='aniIn';
        sel[i].style.display = tmp;}
    $_(classID).style.display = 'block';     
    loadContent(classID, url);  }

function loadContent (classID, url){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById(classID).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;}}

    xmlhttp.open("GET","content/"+url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();}
```

and the HTML5:

```
<!-- Header Areas: (Constent visual)--> 
<header>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="checkPage('aboutPage', 'about.html');return false">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="checkPage('productPage', 'projects.html');return false">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="checkPage('contactPage', 'contact.html');return false">Contact</a></li>
</header>

<!-- Content Areas: (Variable visual)-->
<div id="contentBody">
    <section id="aboutPage"></section>
    <section id="productPage"></section>
    <section id="contactPage"></section>
</div>

<!-- Footer Area: (Constant visual)-->
<footer></footer>
```

previously posted with no answer at: [Previous Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747783/transistion-with-ajax-and-css3)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747783/transistion-with-ajax-and-css3. Brandon, please have a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions.

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions. Think about what you want to achieve and whether you really need an animation or only a transition. Ask yourself "what are the steps my script has to achieve to create such an effect"? Is it a good idea to add the class *before* the content is loaded?

Comment: I get what your saying.  Thank you for the reference, I understand the difference a little better now.  The document says if I am using animations I should be able to do what I need without javascript but I will have to read more into that one.  I see either being a acceptable usage for what I am doing (Not worried about backwards support for this template- gonna tell those who can't to either get on a computer that can or update your browser) although transitions would allow more people to visit.  Back to the books try and post a solution soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried several ways after @Zeta referenced MDN website.  I decided to stay with animation element because I can set the effect such as a bounce or position movement speeds( progressive slow down ).

The first attempt I wanted to try pure CSS but I couldn't get it and I haven't received any feedback on why [question to why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899641/dynamic-page-transitions).

Then I tried to do it [with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900961/page-slide-without-jquery) and had some success. I do have one issue with the script right now but this is a official fix to what I was trying.  (Note: Current issue is the first Link clicked will not transition, I may have a solution though)

See the links for code solutions.